# TikZ + PGF function Plotting: Is there a max(a,b) function?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to plot a function with TikZ and PGF. This function contains a max operator (returning the greater value of the given two parameters).

I want to do the following:

```
\documentclass[
    headsepline,
    parskip=full-
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fadings,calc,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,trees,positioning,arrows,chains,shapes.geometric,decorations.pathreplacing,decorations.pathmorphing,shapes,matrix,shapes.symbols,shapes} %für die Schemata
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$]

    % function that should use the max(a,b) function
    \addplot [domain=0:90, samples=90]{max{0,1-x/20}};
    \addlegendentry{test function}

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I am using MikTex and when I compile the above I get the following error message:

> ```
> PGF Math: Sorry, an internal routine of the floating point unit]'. 
> (in 'max{0,1-x/20}'). ... samples=90]{max{0,1-x/20}};
> ```

Because I cant find any reference to the `max` function I assume it does not even exist. What am I doing wrong or how can I immitate this behaviour?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Ok I just edited my inital post.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, `max` is there, but you have to put its arguments in *round* brackets

```
max(a,b)
```

or even

```
max(a,b,c,d,e)
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass[
    headsepline,
    parskip=full-
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.11}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$]

    % function that should use the max(a,b) function
    \addplot [domain=0:90, samples=90] {max(0,1-x/20)};
    \addlegendentry{test function}

    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```